# How to color half page?

Tags: color, patching

I used `color` to color my page. I want a horizontal (halfway) colored patch which begins from the midpoint and ends at the right end of the page. (Only for the first page and not for the complete document.) I've used the following commands from the package.

`\usepackage{color}
\color{white}
\pagecolor{black}`

Comment: Just to be clear: Only one page coloured halfway from top to middle of the page?

Comment: @Werner yes only one page but not from the top to middle, please see the edit. It should be from the mid of the page to the right end of the same. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following example uses [`eso-pic`](//ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) to tap into the shipout mechanism, printing a rectangular block in `B`ack`G`round of the *current* page. The hook is the `LowerLeft` part of the `Page`, so we shift over `.5\paperwidth` and then set a rectangle of appropriate size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

% To this page only, add a background that fills have the page (from the top)
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace*{.5\paperwidth}%
    \color{blue}%
    \rule{.5\paperwidth}{\paperheight}%
  }%
}%

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. Just one problem. rmargin is creating a problem. It is still in the page color. I want my patch-page till the end of that page.

Comment: @Niranjan: Not sure what you mean by rmargin. You can increase the horizontal width of the rectangle to something much larger than `.5\paperwidth` and just let it bleed off the page. For example, `\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}`...

Comment: Yes. Did it. It worked. Thank you so much.